# "Native module cannot be null" while using openTok reactnative

Tags: javascript, react-native, opentok

i am just trying to implement Video implementation in my react native app. For that i am using "opentok-react-native". But Import the library using the code below gives an error:

```
import { OTSession, OTPublisher, OTSubscriber } from 'opentok-react-native';
```

Error:

```
"Native module cannot be null"
```

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: did you do link?

Comment: did you follow https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native#android-installation

Comment: yes i link using react-native link opentok-react-native

Comment: yes i follow that documentaion and using ios installation